# Configuration Error - Sections must only appear once per config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, razor, umbraco

I'm getting he following exception

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic  for exceptions.
The error shows in the line

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

My web.config file looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="LS.Web" />
        <add namespace="Stimulsoft.Base" />
        <add namespace="Stimulsoft.Report" />
        <add namespace="Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="Umbraco.Web" /><add namespace="Umbraco.Core" /><add namespace="Umbraco.Core.Models" /><add namespace="Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent" /><add namespace="Umbraco.Web.Mvc" /><add namespace="Examine" /><add namespace="Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels" /></namespaces>
    </pages>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
<system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.7.2">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />                
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web></configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  key is in the web.config twice. I've highlighted the lines in red on the image attached.
This can often happen after an Umbraco upgrade in my experience.
You'll like want to keep the bottom one, as that is for a higher version (5.2.7.0)

[image: Image showing duplicate]

Comment: I have removed the below one and now it shows the parse error....

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication'.

`Line 1:  <%@ Application Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>`

the error causing file was global.asax 

my global.asax file looks like

`<%@ Application Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>`

Comment: Is it possible at all you removed the wrong one? The one remaining should be the one that shows 5.2.7.0 (the one at the bottom of the image marked in red). If that doesn't work, maybe even try using the earlier version number (the one above marked in red).
Without being able to run the project it's hard to know for definite.

Comment: I tried the earlier version 5.0.0.0
`<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`
Still the problem occurs

Here is the version information

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4465.0

Comment: Your web.config shows that your MVC version is 5.2.7.0:

<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

So I believe your key should be:

<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Comment: Changed the key as suggested but still the same problem occurs.
Any other way to fix it???????????

Comment: Did the issue occur as part of an upgrade? Is the solution under source control?

Comment: Yes, while installing umbraco I'm facing this issue